# How can generalize this postgresql history trigger function to work on any table?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Consider the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE subscriptions
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  state text NOT NULL CHECK (state IN ('trial', 'expired', 'active', 'cancelled')),
  created_at timestamptz NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE subscriptions_history (LIKE subscriptions);
ALTER table subscriptions_history ADD COLUMN change_type CHARACTER VARYING(6);
ALTER table subscriptions_history ADD COLUMN change_time timestamp without time zone;
ALTER TABLE subscriptions_history ADD CONSTRAINT subscriptions_history_change_type_check CHECK ((((change_type)::text = 'INSERT'::text) OR ((change_type)::text = 'UPDATE'::text) OR ((change_type)::text = 'DELETE'::text)));
```

I have written the following trigger function, which inserts a row to `subscriptions_history` upon every change (insert, update, delete) in `subscriptions` table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_to_subscriptions_history()
    RETURNS TRIGGER 
    SET SCHEMA 'public'
    LANGUAGE plpgsql 
    AS $$
    DECLARE 
        current_row RECORD;
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            current_row := NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            current_row := OLD;
        END IF;
    
        INSERT INTO subscriptions_history (id, state, created_at, change_type, change_time) VALUES (current_row.id, current_row.state, current_row.created_at, TG_OP, now());
    
        RETURN current_row;
    END;
    $$;
```

Trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS subscriptions_trigger ON subscriptions;
CREATE TRIGGER subscriptions_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON subscriptions 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_to_subscriptions_history();
```

This implementation works fine, but I have numerous tables which need a history like this, and I  do not want to write a trigger function to each and every one of them. I would like to generalize the function `add_to_subscriptions_history()` so that it can handle any table.

My only idea is to somehow give the table and its history table to the trigger function as a parameter, and iterate over the records columns during insertion.
How can I do this? Any alternative ideas, scripts?

Comment: Take a look at a blog I wrote some time ago [History](http://aklaver.org/wordpress/2012/06/) that was my solution to this problem. At the time Postgres did not have native  JSON support, hence the use of ```hstore```.  Today I would use JSON.

Comment: I like your idea of storing key/value pairs in some kind of structure, this is a good solution (both hstore and JSON). This would also make it unnecessary to create separate history tables for every table, which is a plus. 
However this solution would make querying a lot more harder. Due to this, I still prefer implementing a unique trigger function for every table. I am looking for a solution which preserves the structure of my history table(s).